# Delete,update the document based on a key in an array

Tags: java, mongodb

I have a key 11-07-2018 under which there are 3 values named( "testing" : 2, "analysis" : 8,"dev" : 4) as below..

```
"Name":"Samaja"
"Dates":[{
         11-07-2018: {
                       "testing" : 2,
                        "analysis" : 8,
                         "dev" : 4
                      }
             }]
```

I want to update the document based on the key(11-07-2018),and delete the exiting values ( "testing" : 2, "analysis" : 8,"dev" : 4) and insert the new values("code":9,"tt":6) based on the same key(11-07-2018).

Answer (score 1):

```
db.test.update(
  {  "Name":"Samaja", //to filter documents. Anything can be used. 
    "Dates.11-07-2018":{$exists:true} //mandatory, otherwise update will throw an error
  },
  {$set: 
      {"Dates.$.11-07-2018":{"code":9,"tt":6}}
  },
  {multi:false //can be set to true if multiple document need to be updated
  }
)
```

EDIT
if you want to add fields to existing document, the code is slightly different :

```
BasicDBObject searchQuery = new BasicDBObject().append("Name", "Samaja").append("Dates.11-07-2018", new BasicDBObject().append("$exists", true));

        BasicDBObject updateQuery = new BasicDBObject();
        updateQuery.append("$set", new BasicDBObject().append("Dates.$.11-07-2018.code", 9).append("Dates.$.11-07-2018.cc", 2));

        collection.updateOne(searchQuery, updateQuery);
```

Comment: Thank You for your Valuable response to my question.. It was useful in mongoshell .. But I'm Trying to solve this issue  in Java with MongoDB..Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Are you using a particular tool, as spring data mongo for example?

Comment: No, I'm not using any tool ,Im trying to solve this in java coding

Comment: Im trying to  insert a new value i.e.,"cc":"2"  after "dev":4..? inside the document(11//7/2018).

Comment: and? just a .append()

Comment: mydesired document is 11.7.2018:[{"dev":4,"cc":2}]..But im getting output as 11.7.2018:[{"dev":4},{"cc":2}]

Comment: can you send your code? Surprised you have an array.

Comment: my desired output: "name":"ssss",
"dates":[{
11/7/2018:{"testing" : 2,
                        "analysis" : 8,
                         "dev" : 4,
                          "cc":2 }}]

Answer (score 0):

Cannot test in java, but this should be the way :

```
BasicDBObject searchQuery = new BasicDBObject().append("Name", "Samaja").append("Dates.11-07-2018",new BasicDBObject().append("$exists",true));

BasicDBObject updateQuery = new BasicDBObject();
updateQuery.append("$set", new BasicDBObject().append("Dates.$.11-07-2018", new BasicDBObject().append("code",9).append("tt":6)));

collection.update(searchQuery, updateQuery);
```

Comment: Thank You for your response. It was Working.., I rechanged the code based on my requirement.